# How to use the variable result for another calculation python

Tags: python

I have this function and I want to save the result of a calculation and use it in another calculation. I am new to python and as you can see I declare new variables, but I can't do that for n times and I know I need to use a for loop but can't define how. Can you help me

```
def aprox_ln(x,n):
    a=(1+x)/2
    print('a0',a);
    g=math.sqrt(x)
    print('g0',g)

    anew = (a+g)/2
    gnew = math.sqrt(a*g)

    aa = (anew * gnew)/2
    bb= math.sqrt(anew*gnew)
   
             .
             .
             .
#  and so on for n times 
    
print(aprox_ln(5,10))
```

EDIT:
I want to use the result of the variables A and G to calculate A1 = (A + G) / 2 and G1 = math.sqrt (A * G), and then use the result of A1 and G1 to calculate A2 and G2 with the same formula and so on until An and Gn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save variables along the way in a repeating manner you can use a list, or you can make a recursive function call.

Appending to lists: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/append

Recursive programming: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/recursion

If you can be more specific in what you want your program to do, we can give you more specific code examples of how to do it.

Update: I've included some code for what I think you would like to do.

```
def aprox_ln(x, n)
    a = 1
    g = x
    lst = []
    for i in range(n):
        a = (a+g)/2
        g = math.sqrt(a*g)
        lst.append((a, g))
    return lst
```

Comment: I want to use the result of the variables A and G to calculate A1 = (A + G) / 2 and G1 = math.sqrt (A * G), and then use the result of A1 and G1 to calculate A2 and G2 with the same formula and so on until An and Gn